# How to open the same instance of a previously closed window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I implemented the control basics sample from the Kinect for Windows toolkit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn188701.aspx to control the cursor with a users hand, but when I click on a sub window and then re open the main window with the hand cursor doesn't show.

My question is how do I open a new window without closing the previous window and then navigate back to the same instance of that window, not a new instance?

This is how I call a new window in my main window class:

```
private void trainingBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var newForm = new TrainingFrm(); //create your new form.
     newForm.Show(); //show the new form.
     this.Close(); //only if you want to close the current form. 
}
```

And this is how I reopen the main window, but it creates anew instance of the main window which I don't want.

```
private void homeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var newForm = new MainWindow(); //create your new form.
     newForm.Show(); //show the new form.
     this.Close(); //only if you want to close the current form.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you  need  is composition

Here how it should look your mainWindow class

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private trainingWindow _trainingWindow;   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonGoTraining_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_trainingWindow== null)
        {
         _trainingWindow=  new trainingWindow(this);   
        }

        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;  
        _trainingWindow.Show();
        _trainingWindow.Visibility  = Visibility.Visible;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
    }
}
```

and here is your training class

```
public partial class trainingWindow : Window
    {
        private MainWindow _mainWindow; 
        public trainingWindow(MainWindow mainWindow )
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mainWindow = mainWindow;  
        }

        private void biuttonBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
            _mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
    }
```

here is the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,38,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195" Click="buttonGoTraining_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>



<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.trainingWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="trainingWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,33,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" Click="biuttonBack_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without having to merger the xaml? I was thinking of not closing the main form so that the training form opens in front of it and the in the home button click set trainingFrm to Visibility.Collapsed and don't call a new instance of MainWindow. Would this work?

Comment: just try it it 'will  work as expected I'm not calling any new instance it's always the same instance try it

Answer (score 1):

Simply *hide* it, and not *close*.

If you need to show a fresh information after show, just bind a new data to its view model.

Comment: I figured out how to keep main window open in background, just comment out ``this.close` but how do I navigate back to it from the HomeBtn click.At present this click event creates a new instance of the window.

Comment: what that "navigate" exactly means ? you hide it, so it become invisible. one time you want to show it again, but with different information (I presume that you mean saying navigate) you bind a new data to its view model and that new data populates UI.

Comment: I want to show MainWindow again but not a new instance of it, I want to open the intial MainWindow . In this case the code is calling `new MainWindow(); `n which is no good as I need the original window..

Comment: Remove new. You need Show() call *on the same instance*.